# max ram for dell motherboard "0gdg8y"

Tags: memory, desktop-computer

I am using dell computer. Its Mother board spec is :
http://www.findlaptopdriver.com/mainboard-dell-0gdg8y-specs-38317201215/

I want to upgrade my RAM. now it has 2*3 = 6GB
on spec, It says max 8G RAM

2 * 240-pin DDR3 DIMM slots Supports Dual Channel DDR3 1333/1066 MHz non-ECC, un-buffered memory
(Max 8GB on 64-bit Operating Systems)

I want to know, does it mean max 2*4G or 2*8G?

thanks,

Comment: Maximum total memory 8GB; there is only one way that is support by your hardware and it's not 8GB*2